# Pass arguments to function class with do_action()

Tags: functions, actions

I'm trying to develop a "simple" script where i can create a filename with a timestamp of the last edit. For this I'm trying to code a class – but I'm having problems to pass an argument to add_action. I placed this script in functions.php to fire it on my will with do_action.

```
class tme_form_filehash
{

    public $args;

    public function __construct( $args ) {
        $this->args = $args
        add_action( 'init_tme_form_filehash', array($this, 'tme_form_filehash'), $args );
    }

    public function tme_form_filehash( $args )
    {
        echo $args;
    }

}

$tme_form_filehash = new tme_form_filehash( $args );
```

and somewhere in my theme I placed

```
<?php do_action('init_tme_form_filehash','hello'); ?>
```

but still there is no echo at my wished place...what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: To clear some things: of course this is not the real script. But this should just show my basic problem with the script to pass an argument in my class for the "real" script.

Comment: _somewhere_ should be after when `tme_form_filehash` has been initiated. Where did you add it ? Also third parameter of `add_action` should be priority not a string like `$args`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply the add_action and do_action in combination with class object, you have to use a static function to access your class.

Try this code with your own wording/variables:

```
class My_Plugin {

    protected static $_instance = null;

    // Static function used to access this class
    public static function get_instance() {
        if ( self::$_instance == null ) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        add_action('MY_HOOK_NAME', array($this, 'MY_HOOK_FUNCTION'), $args);
    }

    public function MY_HOOK_FUNCTION($args) { 
        echo $args;
    }

}
```

Then initialize your class:

```
My_Plugin::get_instance();
```

Finally you can use the do_action:

```
do_action('MY_HOOK_NAME', 'hello my test')
```